indices.query.bool.max_clause_count behavior in 8.x
Planning to migrate elastic cluster from 7.17 to 8.10.
We have set the value for indices.query.bool.max_clause_count : 200000 in elastic 7.17.
While going through the release notes we found that indices.query.bool.max_clause_count setting is deprecated with 8.x in favor of dynamic settings based on RAM/CPU (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/search-settings.html).
We have couple of questions wrt to same,

What is the formula to calculate value for  indices.query.bool.max_clause_count in 8.10?

Are we using RAM and CPU of physical server to calculate the value of ? or we are using heap search thread pool ?

Which search thread pool property is used to calculate value of indices.query.bool.max_clause_count what is the default value?

Are there any log to know the value of indices.query.bool.max_clause_count for currenct es cluster ?

Any other property as a substitute in elastic 8.10?


We have not migrated the cluster yet to 8.10 going through the release notes.

That's correct, it's deprecated (see PR #81525 and corresponding issue #46433)


What is the formula to calculate value for indices.query.bool.max_clause_count in 8.10?


The formula can be found here, basically:
max(1024, (int) maxHeapInMb * 64 / threadPoolSize)



Are we using RAM and CPU of physical server to calculate the value of ? or we are using heap search thread pool ?


The allocated heap is used (i.e. as set by -Xmx) and the number of allocated processors (i.e. as returned by os.allocated_processors as you'll see below)


Which search thread pool property is used to calculate value of indices.query.bool.max_clause_count what is the default value?


The thread_pool.search.size value you can get from
GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults&filter_path=**.thread_pool.search.size

=> 
{
  "defaults": {
    "thread_pool": {
      "search": {
        "size": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}

which is set using the formula int((# of allocated processors * 3) / 2) + 1
In my case, os.allocated_processors = 1, so size = int((1 * 3) / 2) + 1 = 2


Are there any log to know the value of indices.query.bool.max_clause_count for currenct es cluster ?


GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults&filter_path=**.max_clause_count

=> 

{
  "defaults": {
    "indices": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "max_clause_count": "4096"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



Any other property as a substitute in elastic 8.10?


Not that I know of
